# Match string with database in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

A user will come on website and fill the registration form. Registration form has a question displayed below 
 Which subjects you want to study?

Answer by user -  I want to study Hindi and english

```
 sentence="I want to study Hindi and english"
```

I have 2 database displayed below. Now the answer by the user should match with the one database table with maximum accuracy , The database table matching with maximum accuracy should get selected . 
I am not able to match with accuracy  and if the users write in a different way like

> 1. I am studying hindi and english
> 2. I want to study hindi and english .

The above 2 sentences means the same but proper matching with database table is not being done by me properly. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Database:

```
 Class_A

   id                     subject
    1                     Hindi
    2                   English
    3                   Physics

Class_B

   Id                     subject
    1                     Hindi
    2                      Math
    3                   Science
```

view.py

```
def submission(request):
    obj = Registration.objects.latest('id')
    obj1 = Registration.objects.filter(name__contains=obj1)
    for a in obj1:
        sentence= a.subject
        word = sentence.split()
        class_a=class_A.objects.all()
        class_b=class_B.objects.all()

        if class_a in  word:
            return render(request,'data/submission.html',{'Class':'Your Are in Class A'})
        elif class_b in  word:
            return render(request, 'data/submission.html', {'Class': 'You are in Class B'})
```

Registration is user registration database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you need [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains)

```
if class_a.filter(subject__icontains=word).exists():
```

more details in example:

```
class Class_A(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)

In [9]: Class_A.objects.values_list('subject', flat=True)
Out[9]: ['Hindi', 'English', 'Physics']

In [10]: Class_A.objects.filter(subject__icontains='Hindi').exists()
Out[10]: True

In [11]: word = ['i', 'want', 'to', 'study', 'Hindi', 'and', 'english']

In [12]: Class_A.objects.filter(subject__in=word).exists()
Out[12]: True
```

Comment: Error occurred after using this:-                                                                       The view data.views.submission didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: do `print(word)`

Comment: word:
['i', 'want', 'to', 'study', 'Hindi', 'and', 'english']
                                                                                                                       But its not match and display accurate ans.

Comment: i added details, please look and try.

Comment: I have also applied the same code, but it is not working in my system 
i think  Class_A.objects.filter(subject__icontains=word).exists() is not working, so please guide me.......

Comment: `Class_A.objects.filter(subject__in=word).exists()`

Comment: Hello . Thanks for the efforts. The system is working fine now with one word subject added in a database Table Like Hindi , English.                                                            But when 2 words or 3 words Subject is added in a database table like English                   literature or Physical education or Environmental Studies. Then the system doesnt work . Like if the user Fills the registration form by writing " I want to study Physical Education "  , Then it doesnt matches because of 2 words subject . Kindly help me in this.

Comment: unfortunately it is not possible to understand details of your new question, just create new and may be or some one else will help you

Answer (score -1):

The built-in difflib library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) may be useful there. There are several other options for fuzzy string matching (Jellyfish, Distance, python-Levenshtein) you might want to have a look at.